# Can I filter by aggregate functions without actually grouping the results?

Tags: mysql, group-by, grouping, having

I guess I'm looking for a shorthand here. Consider the following two queries:

```
select columnA, columnB 
from tableA 
group by columnA, columnB 
having count(1) >1
```

gives me all the value combinations for which duplicates exist.

```
select tA.* 
from tableA 
join (
    select columnA,columnB 
    from tableA 
    group by columnA, columnB 
    having count(1) >1
) xA
    on tA.columnA = xA.columnA 
    and tA.columnB = xA.columnB
```

gives me all the rows that are duplicates, but is long and cumbersome to write.

Is there anything in MySql that gives you the option to filter by groupings without actually grouping the results, like (beware of pseudo-code)

```
select columnA,columnB from tableA having count(1) >1 grouped by columnA, columnB
```

?

Comment: If you are using version 8.0 then you can use [windowed functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html), e.g. SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY ColumnA, ColumnB) AS cnt FROM TableA) AS a WHERE a.cnt > 1;. It's not loads shorter (although I would argue that your original query is not particularly long or cumbersome in the first place) but it is a bit shorter and should be more efficient - [Example on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/99JpbwX8KacgkPDAYLSYGG/0)

Answer (score 0):

If the index by `(columnA, columnB, id)` (or at least by `(columnA, columnB)`) exists then you may use WHERE EXISTS with correlated subquery. `id` in this case is any unique non-NULL expression, primary key column preferred.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM tableA t1
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
               FROM tableA t2
               WHERE t1.columnA = t2.columnA 
                 AND t1.columnB = t2.columnB
                 AND t1.id <> t2.id )
```

Of course this query will give correct output without the index, but I doubt that the performance will be useful in this case.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&rdbms2=mysql_5.7&fiddle=4a4b608092d92d2b063ece786b1bfdb4